# How to assign patch to specified git source?

Tags: yocto, openembedded

In my `foo_git.bb`:

```bash
SRC_URI = "git://github.com/foo/foo.git;branch=main;protocol=https;name=${BPN};destsuffix=git  \
    git://github.com/foo2/foo2;branch=main;protocol=https;name=${FOO2};destsuffix=${FOO2} \
    file://0001-Modify-A_value.patch\
"
```

I want my patch to apply to `foo2` but it always applied to `foo`. ( patch failed )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found `patchdir` appended after the patch can work.

ex:

```
file://0001-Modify-A_value.patch;patchdir=${WORKDIR}/${FOO2_path}
```

Answer (score 0):

From the OE manual

> *Patch files will be copied to `${S}/patches` and then applied to source from within the source directory, `${S}.`*

so for your use case to work your patch filenames should include their base repo name.

For example let’s say 0001-Modify-A_value.patch is as follows:

```diff
diff --git a/my.txt b/my.txt
index fa5cb9a..59369cc 100644
--- a/my.txt
+++ b/my.txt
@@ -1 +1 @@
-I am foo who lives in bar
+I am bar who lives in foo
```

To make it apply to foo2 you must modify it as follows:

```diff
--- foo2/my.txt
+++ foo2/my.txt
@@ -1 +1 @@
-I am foo who lives in bar
+I am bar who lives in foo
```

Bitbake uses Quilt for patching so for errors and so on look at its manual.
Another handy tool by bitbake to help you further is the devtool which is designed to handle tasks like updating a recipe or patching it.